# P=NP implies NL=NP?

Tags: complexity-theory

Does $P=NP \implies NL=P=NP$? The converse $NL=NP \implies NL=P=NP$ is clear.

Assuming $NP=PH=PSPACE$ is not true, if $P=NP$ is there anything else that can be used to show $NL=P=NP$?

Do the $P=NP$ barriers apply to $NL=P$ question or $NL=NP$ question?